# Magento2 - How to add comment for each item in cart page

Tags: magento2

In `Magento 2`, how to add meta information in cart item (order comment) add in each item quote during add to cart ?

If any one has idea about this let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: at pdp page or cart page or checkout page?

Comment: I ask to cart page

Comment: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/add-additional-options-in-magento-2/ - please check this one hope its helpful to you.